# How to star github repo with Github API - What's wrong with my request?

Tags: node.js, github-api, node-request

I'm learning NodeJS and have been trying to play with GithubAPI, using request module. However I can't get put request - to star a repo - working.

Here is my code:

```
        let repo = JSON.parse(response);
        client.get(req.cookies.sessionid, function (err, response) {
            request.put("https://api.github.com/user/starred/" + repo.author + "/" + repo.name, {
                headers:{
                    'User-Agent': 'request',
                    'Authorization':"token "+response,
                    "Content-Length":0,
                }
            }, function (errors, response, body) {
                console.log(errors);
            })
        }
```

It seems to me that I've followed the API [instructions](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository) but here is the response I get : `{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository"}`. However repo owner and name are correct. What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

I've also tried using [this](https://github.com/cheeaun/npm-star) package, but get the same error message. I've also tried altering the auth token and have received a 401 wrong auth error, and I've previously fixed headers errors. Also I double checked the url and repo owner/name are correct.

Comment: Are you sure that in your header token you use your response complete and not one field of it? Or a field of repo? This seems fishy

Comment: Every variable has its expected value, I've also tried this with hardcoded value.

Comment: have you solved it? I am meeting the same problem..

Comment: No sorry never succeeded. If you ever find a solution I'd be glad to read it. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This isn't NodeJS specific, but there must be something wrong with your request. This JS ajax method sets the request type as **PUT** which is used for replacing resources or collections.

As the documentation specifies, a 'starred' request requires no body attribute so the Content-Length header must be set to zero.

```
var addToFavorites = function(repoObj){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'https://api.github.com/user/starred/<the author>/<the repo>',
        type: 'PUT',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token " + authStr); 
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });  
};
```

As for your authentication token, it needs the 'public_repo' scope to utilize starred features, so make sure you define and create your personal access token correctly ahead of time.